Any way to Download the files in a AWS S3 Bucket subfolder?
I have created a S3 bucket. And there is a subfolder under this bucket. I want to use nodejs SDK to download the files inside of this subfolder. I couldn't find any documentation on this.
Can anyone help? I'll really appreciate it.

You will need to list the folder then loop through the objects and download each one individually.

Input the file path as a Key value, like, Key: 'folder1/subfolder1/INV 3378.json'.
const bucketInfo = {
  Bucket:bucketName,
  Key: 'folder1/subfolder1/INV 3378.json',
}
const command = new GetObjectCommand(bucketInfo)

